# Android и кодировка.

Tags: android, кодировка

Вынимаю txt из ассетов, считываю строку, состоящую из русских символов. Присваиваю textview эту строку, вывожу на экран, выводит только знаки вопроса. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Файл, скорее всего, в кодировке win-1251, или подобной. При работе с Android файлы нужно кодировать всегда в UTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо проверить кодировку файла в ассетах и посмотреть на код, коим вынимаете текст. Там наверняка можно задать кодировку. Лучше всего пользовать "utf-8".

Comment: Да, спасибо, файл был ansi, теперь utf-8.

Comment: @Юра Тихонов, пожалуйста)